# Don't understand the output

Tags: java, arrays, for-loop, output

I see no reason why the output for this code segment should be different on the bottom than it is on the top.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {       

        int[] list1 = {2, 4, 8, 16, 32, 64, 128, 256};
        int[] list2 = list1;
        int max = list1.length - 1;
        for (int k = 0; k < list1.length; k++) {
            System.out.print(list1[k] + " ");
            list2[k] = list1[max - k];
        }
        System.out.print("\n");
        for (int k = 0; k < list1.length; k++) {
            System.out.print(list1[k] + " ");
        }
    }
```

OUTPUT:

```
2 4 8 16 32 64 128 256 
256 128 64 32 32 64 128 256
```

The top portion of the output is what list1 is.
I am printing out list1 for the second one as well but I see no reason for it to be different.
list2 changes but list1 never changes.

This is from school and I am just so confused about why the two outputs are different.

EDIT:
I know it has something to do with `list2[k] = list1[max - k];` but I don't understand why this would change list1 in any way.

Comment: If one of our answers has helped you, please accept one as the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`int[]` is a reference type.  That means that the actual value in the `list1` and `list2` variables is just an address of the array.

When you do the following, you're not really copying the array.  You're only copying the address of the array.

```
int[] list2 = list1;
```

Since `list2` and `list1` now point to the same array, any changes that you make to the elements of `list2` will also be made to the elements of `list1`, because they're the same elements.

Comment: Wow, you and everybody else just made this really easy.  I can't thank you enough.

Answer (score 5):

They are different because both variables are pointing to the same object.
To have the same result, replace this line:

```
int[] list2 = list1;
```

to:

```
int[] list2 = list1.clone();
```

Comment: Wow, that pointing to the same objects thing was never explained to us in class.  So to get this straight:    list1 and list2 in the original code use the same set of data even though they have different names?

Comment: Read a little about pointers, in C and Java. It will clarify your understanding about this. :)

Answer (score 3):

Your problem is actually with the following line:

```
int[] list2 = list1;
```

This is causing you to have two references to the SAME object in memory.  Thus, when you do the assignment (where you thought your problem was), you're putting the last element into the first slot, the second to last into the second slot, and so on, until you get to the middle, and then you're copying the new values back in, which means they don't actually change.

What you probably want to do is make a separate copy of `list1` with the `clone()` method, like so:

```
int[] list2 = list1.clone();
```

HOWEVER (as GRC pointed out), there's no reason to even make the copy in this case, because your plan is to overwrite all the contents anyway.  So, you can just do the following:

```
int[] list2 = new int[list1.length];
```

Comment: This is what was given to me, I just can't figure out why that would be a problem.

Comment: I would not do the list.clone() at all because you are copying list1 than overwriting it later.